# How do I get rid of flash of unstyled content in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app with several nested components.

A Cards component:

```
  async loadAllArticles() {
    await this.categoryLoader();
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.loadAllArticles();

  }

  render() {

if (this.state.isLoading) {
  return <Loading />;
}
return (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={MainStyles.cardsScrollViewContainer}
    style={MainStyles.cardsScrollView}
  >

    {Platform.OS === "web" ? (
      <Filters search={false} />
    ) : null}

    <View style={MainStyles.cardRowContainer}>
      {this.state.articleGroups.map((articleGroup, index) => (
        <CardRow
          articleGroup={articleGroup}
          count={index}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
);
```

}

A CardRow component:

```
  <Fragment>

    <View style={MainStyles.articleGroupContainer}>
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        colors={['rgba(0,0,0,1)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          height: 50,
        }}
      />

      <Text style={MainStyles.articleGroupText}>{this.props.articleGroup.category}</Text>

    </View>

    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    >
      {this.props.articleGroup.data.map((article, index) => (
        <Card
          article={article}
          key={index + "-main"}
        />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  </Fragment>
```

Now my big problem is that my Card component and my LinearGradient components seemingly need to do some sort of loading before they are visible.

I've tried putting all sorts of loading checks after different events, but I am still getting this flash of unstyled content - whereas I'd much rather have the loading widget appear until everything was ready to render correctly.

Is there a way to do this in React Native?

Comment: I'm not sure if you had to add `async componentDidMount()` and `await this.loadAllArticles();` to try? And maybe add else to wrap the other render

Comment: @高鵬翔 No change, is exactly the same. I'm going to try to find a workaround

Comment: There is an another solution but not very recommend, maybe you could use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` instead because it work before `componentDidMount` ? then you don't have to return loading and setstate